# Control where automatic line breaks occur in text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a section of my page that shows user addresses. The area the addresses can show in isn't very wide, so for longer addresses, the text will wrap to another line. I want to have the text  only wrap at the end of "address elements", for instance, if the user has an address like:

```
4, Long name street name Street, City name, Place, Imaginary Republic of Central Flaffapus
```

the address should wrap like this:

```
4, Long name street name Street,
City name, Place,
Imaginary Republic of Central Flaffapus
```

but not like this:

```
4, Long name street name Street,
City name, Place, Imaginary
Republic of Central Flaffapus
```

Also not like this:

```
4,
Long name street name Street,
City name,
Place,
Imaginary Republic of Central Flaffapus
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) `&nbsp;` for the spaces you *dont* want it to break on, and regular spaces for the ones where you want to allow breaks.

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world, this is a job for the `<wbr>` tag, which indicates [a line-break *opportunity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr).

Browser compatibility is [hit-or-miss](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html). IE supports it from 5.5 to 7, but not afterwards.

Comment: Ouch. That looks really handy, but the weird compatibility makes it difficult to use.

Comment: It's okay, since it works fine with Chrome, Safari and Opera. Also, note that the article is 2 years old. The guide is detailed, not comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is consistent, you can split it on the commas and add in `<br>` tags

```
var addr = "4, Long name street name Street, City name, Place, Imaginary Republic of Central Flaffapus".split(",");
addr[2]="<br>" + addr[2];
addr[4]="<br>" + addr[4];
myElement.innerHTML = addr.join(",");
```

Or with regex:

```
var addr = "4, Long name street name Street, City name, Place, Imaginary Republic of Central Flaffapus";
addr.replace(/([^,]*).([^,]*).([^,]*).([^,]*).([^,]*)/,"$1,$2,<br>$3,$4,<br>$5");
```

Comment: My problem is that the break won't always be in those locations - for instance, if the street name and the city name are very short, both should appear on the same line.

Comment: @Oliver that's quite difficult to do. :P  Normally these kinds of displays of data are in a predefined format rather than dynamic to their content.

Answer (score -1):

Insert the `<br>` tag at the end of the lines you want it to break on.

Comment: I don't want to break after every part of the address, or something like that. I want the text to wrap as neccessary, but not to wrap halfway though a part of the address.

Comment: @Oliver I see you have already accepted an answer.  What I was thinking is if you always insert line breaks after Street and Place then it would always break there and not someplace else.